# selenium bs4 парсинг динамической таблицы

Tags: python, selenium, bs4

Ковыряю с помощью seleniuma + bs4 вот такую динамическую табличку, мне надо ее распарсить, откуда, куда, и номер телефона вытащить

[введите сюда описание ссылки](https://trucks.ati.su/?Weight=20&FromGeo=1_151&ExactFromGeos=true&ToGeo=1_153&ExactToGeos=true)

код Python

```
rs = requests.get(f"https://trucks.ati.su/?Weight=20&FromGeo=1_151&ExactFromGeos=true&ToGeo=1_153&ExactToGeos=true")
soup = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'html.parser')
# name_driver = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#root > main > div:nth-child(3) > div > div.SearchResultsStyles__StyledResultsListTable-sc-1wkbcgr-2.ResultCardListStyles-sc-16v3r1q-0.dbfAsW > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.contacts-and-comments-wrapper > div > div.ContactsStyles-sc-4caz6o-0.iozEQN > div.firm-params') забирает только 1 контант
tr = soup.find("table")
print(tr)
    
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/main/div[3]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/span[7]/span').click()
time.sleep(5)
```

как ее крутить всю в цикле после прокликов? у меня с помощью xpath забирает только 1 контакт, а если просто через selenium то с помощью pandas read_html , бонально он забирает только верхушку таблицу
я застрял, друзья, помогите

Comment: у них есть [api](https://ati.su/landings/apiatisu/)

Comment: однако, очевидно

Comment: тогда зачем парсить html?

Comment: вы не понимаете задачу, прочитайте еще раз, там написано "номер телефона вытащить" Я студент делаю в практических целях, что в этом такого не законого?